# How can I remove my NodeJs application from Cpanel?

Tags: node.js, hosting, cpanel

I started my nodejs application as I followed these instructions: [how to deploy an APP NodeJS Through cPanel](https://hosting-marketers.com/news/2019/07/05/how-to-deploy-an-app-nodejs-through-cpanel/#.Xq6KlGVR200).

However, after running my .js script, I can't edit/stop/delete the application.

On trying to delete, an error shows up :

> Can't acquire lock for app:app

Please help

Comment: Did you find this solution @tim Mwaura?

Comment: My hosting provider solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it was a problem that the hosting providers can solve for you. My hosting providers solved the problem :D

Answer (score 4):

delete file .lock from nodevenv directory which is in your root folder.

Answer (score 3):

ITS VERY SIMPLE THIS IS HOW I SOLVED

DELETE FOLDERS like I created node project named app

remove all folders named with 'app' inside public-html, home/example , nodevenv

Now open npm software in cpanel refresh it will be removed now.

Now create a new app now

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project folder in the nodevenv then try removing the project in the nodejs web applications